# @silevis reactgrid datatable styling full width

Tags: datatable

I am Using @silevis React grid Data table , but the issue is table is not getting full width,
i want the table should align full width as per the page width , below i am attaching the screenshot and the code below , any one of you could you please help me , i have tried in many ways, but no proper solution found.

Thanks in advance

```html
<div style={{width:"100%"}}
<ReactGrid
                enableFillHandle
                enableRangeSelection
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                onCellsChanged={handleChanges}

                onColumnResized={handleColumnResize}
              />
              </div>
```

[image]